# What scope should i apply for the libraries used in my jar ,?

Tags: java, maven, gradle, build.gradle, dependency-management

I am developing an application which will be published to nexus repository used as a dependency by other applications. 
I am using gradle for the build, and have applied the maven plugin.

When i do a gradle install, the dependency scope in the generated pom is automatically applied as 'runtime' for the libraries that i have added as dependencies.

I am using "implementation" for adding my dependencies.

What is the recommended scope for the libraries i my case ?

I see compile would have been useful , but is now deprecated. Should i use compileClasspath ?

Thanks !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The scope of the dependencies is controlled by the [configuration](https://docs.gradle.org/current/dsl/org.gradle.api.artifacts.Configuration.html) you define them in in the `dependencies { }` block.

Gradle has [great table with descriptions](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/java_library_plugin.html#sec:java_library_configurations_graph) as to when you should use them.

Most commonly, you'll use these two:

- `implementation` - This is where you should declare dependencies which are purely internal and not meant to be exposed to consumers.
- `api` - This is where you should declare dependencies which are transitively exported to consumers, for compile.

Comment: Thanks Francisco. When i use api instead of implementation in my module's build.gradle, the build fails with the error - Gradle DSL method not found: api()  -- any thoughts on this ?

Comment: `api` configuration is available from the [`Java Library Plugin`](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/java_library_plugin.html)